# How to avoid multiplied data in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table A and table B with the below data

```
A
--
org location
123  001
123  002
123  003

B
--
org  sub_inv
123  001_a
123  002_a
123  003_a
```

Now i need to write a query to get the results like

```
org, sub_inv, loc
123   001_a   001
123   002_a   002
123   003_a   003
```

The below query is giving the multiplied data.Please help me with the suggestions.

```
select
from a,b
where a.org=b.org
```

Thanks,
Mamatha

Comment: There is no join on `org` which will give you the results you want.  Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: What is your problem. Query is ok you just need to list columns you want to select.

Comment: is location always 3 characters and does it always relate to the first 3 characters of sub_inv?  and what is the data type for location?

Comment: Very poorly explained. basically i cant join anything if org being the PK's is all 123?

Answer (score 1):

If I assume location is always 3 characters and it always relates to the first 3 characters of sub_inv; then you need to join on a substring of sub_inv in addition to org.

I'm assuming 3 records in A * 3 records in B is giving you the 9 records and you only want 3.  Given the only other correlation  provided is the location code I'm assuming sub_inv contains location

I'm not a fan of the , notation in a from clause so I re-wrote it a bit.

```
SELECT A.org, B.sub_inv, A.loc
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
 on A.Org = B.Org
and cast(A.Location as varchar2(3)) = substr(sub_inv,1,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
select a.org
      ,b.sub_inv
      ,a.loc
from a
     join b on (a.org          = b.org 
                and a.location = substr(b.sub_inv,1,length(a.location))
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like this is what you're looking for. You need to elaborate more on what you're asking. From your question all you were asking is how to do a select on a join.

`select a.org as org, b.sub_inv as sub_inv, a.location as loc
from a,b
where a.org = b.org`

Comment: 3 rec in A * 3 rec in B = 9 records on org desired result is 3.  The problem as I see it is a missing join on sub_inv to loc on a substring of sub_inv. but that's assuming a few things on my part.